# JQuery UI Tab selecetion not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to implement JQuery Tabs on my page. But, the problem is, when I click on the tabs,the UI of the tabs do not change.The selected tab always remains selected and the unselected tab is always unselected. I am not able to figure out which tab is actually clicked.Since, I have used "bind" to bind the click event on the tabs,the implementation is working as expected.Since I am totally new to JQuery UI stuff, I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is the jsp code for the tabs(written as mentioned on the net).

```
<div id="tabs" style="margin-top: 100px; width: 100%;margin-left:20%;">
    <ul>
        <li id="allocated"><a href="#tabs-1">Allocated</a></li>
        <li id="pending"><a href="#tabs-2">Pending</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In javascript file :

```
$('#tabs',container).tabs();
```

I have written different bind event for both the tabs as follows :

```
$("#allocated", container).unbind("click").click(function() {
});

$("#pending", container).unbind("click").click(function() {
});
```

Do I need to change the state of the tabs manually or it should change by itself.

Comment: Check this sample:http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#entry-examples

Answer (score 0):

There is no content to display for your tabs, that's why this is not working properly :

```
<div id="tabs" style="margin-top: 100px; width: 100%;margin-left:20%;">
    <ul>
        <li id="allocated"><a href="#tabs-1">Allocated</a>
        </li>
        <li id="pending"><a href="#tabs-2">Pending</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And no need to specify `container` in your selector :

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

> [» Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/83ojxf6k/)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are unbinding the click event? This will stop the click event added by `$('#tabs').tabs();`.
If you want to do custom actions on the click, you just need to define the click:

```
$("#allocated", container).click(function() {
    alert(1);
});

$("#pending", container).click(function() {
    alert(2)
});
```